# Listing Joined tables in MXD using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, mxd, mapping

I've a question about arcpy List* modules.

I have a quite large amount of data on ArcSDE Server.

Earlier I made a list of the feature classes, and tables in the mxd-s placed there using da.Walk and ListFeatureClasses/ListTableViews.

Now I'd like to list the joined tables too, but I've no further idea how to do it.

Actually is it possible to get these relations?